# How to prefix LWC Combobox items with several white spaces?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I've been using the LWC Combobox to implement a requirement that involves having indentation (prefixing with white spaces or just padding-left) on the Combobox items/options. The idea is to have a visual interpretation of the Accounts Hierarchy... something like the following but with white spaces instead of underscores,

- _Parent Acc
- ___Parent Sub Account A
- ______Parent Sub Sub Account A.1
- ___Parent Sub Account B

Example code of what I tried,

*accountCombobox.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-combobox 
        name="accountsCombobox" 
        variant="label-hidden" 
        value={selectedAccountId} 
        placeholder="Select an Account" 
        options={accounts}>
    </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

*accountCombobox.js*

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class accountCombobox extends LightningElement {
    // Public properties:
    @api selectedAccountId;

    // @track accounts = [{label: "Parent Acc", value: "1"}, {label: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Parent Sub Account A", value: "1.1"},
    // {label: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Parent Sub Sub Account A.1", value: "1.1.1"},
    // {label: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Parent Sub Sub Account B", value: "1.2"}];
    @track accounts = [{label: "Parent Acc", value: "1"}, {label: "   Parent Sub Account A", value: "1.1"},
     {label: "      Parent Sub Sub Account A.1", value: "1.1.1"},
     {label: "   Parent Sub Sub Account B", value: "1.2"}];

}
```

*accountCombobox.js-meta.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

In the snippet for the.js file you can find two accounts arrays, now using &nbsp and another one using white spaces.

Using the `&nbsp;` for the white spaces it prints literally `&nbsp;`
Using white spaces trims them to one white space only like it's shown on the next picture,

[image]

and this is the corresponding generated HTML for a item of the combobox,

[image]

I've tried to change the CSS style that is trimming these white spaces (*white-space: nowrap;*) but no luck. I believe we can't change much on the Combobox child components CSS classes/styles.

I also tried to use *button-menu* with *menu-items* to behave like a Combobox and although I was able to have a visual representation of the Account hierarchy, when I change the Button Menu label with the selected item, the width of the menu-button adapts to the size of the label and I also wasn't able to fix a width.

Any ideas on what I could try to achieve the desired indentation (by showing the white spaces)?
Do you think it is possible to try and somehow escape the white spaces trimming?

Thank you very much for your attention and help and let me know if more details are needed (sorry for not posting the code on my first attempt... such a n00b)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please read [ask]. Could you please include a minimal code example that could help us reproduce your problem entirely?

Comment: Update: LWC cmpts do not inherit CSS styless and the checkbox LWC standard component currently styling hooks doesn't allow the change of this specific styling to get the desired visual representation. I would say that the options here are to override the CSS class or build a component from scratch (it's extra work but it offers more liberty to control the styling. Please understand that with so many talented people out there I had to try and ask this. Thank you!